# Access Microsoft sql database from Folder

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

I have MS sql database in folder on my computer and i am trying to connect to that database from asp.net(c#) application but it is throwing errors. Any help please.

My Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add 
<add name="con" connectionString="Server=kuldeep;Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\jambtjh.mdf;
Initial Catalog=jambtjh;Integrated Security=True; ID=sa;Password=123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<connectionStrings>
```

c# Code-

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd,cmd1;
    SqlDataReader dr,dr1;
    con.Open();
    string str = "select * from testtable";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
}
```

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd,cmd1;

Comment: what errors,can you please paste them

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Keyword not supported: 'id'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'id'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick one i have shared the error @ TheGameiswar

Comment: I can't see where you're using `id` in ths code you have posted.

Comment: it is here in web.config ----Integrated Security=True; ID=sa;Password=123;

Comment: use "User ID" instead of ID

Comment: Thanks for the quick one @Vandita but ....Now it is giving the this error : --System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Cannot open database "jambtjh" requested by the login. The login failed.

 
Login failed for user 'sa'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: @kuldeepsingh Please edit the question accordingly. And as the exception says, login failed please check password and sa user has got sufficient rights to access database.

Comment: Thanks @Vandita. I have checked the credentials and i am using these in other app also. Here i am trying to access the database from folder this is the only difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the *.mdf file in the App_Data folder of an ASP.NET app you can use this.

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

No authentication is required.

Comment: Thanks@Vandita  when using this (a)  <add name="con" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|jambtjh.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />      .............The error is ---

Comment: erroro--System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: This time another error for the ----  <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=omnsin_gdb;User ID=omnsin_omnsin;Password=baby@1977" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="updateKRA" connectionString="Data Source=kuldeep;Initial Catalog=jambtjh;User ID=sa;Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: error - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: @kuldeepsingh have you kept your .mdf file in App_Data folder of Application?

Comment: Yes yes file is there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you @Vandita for you help. You are right id and password is not required. 
I have added few things to your answer and it is working for me.
Just sharing the line here :

```
<add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB   AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\jambtjh.mdf;
        Initial Catalog=jambtjh;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```